# Breaker buzzing even after replacement

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Ok, so. I just built a small home for myself. I did all the wiring with the help of a friend. I just now got a solar setup, 8 months later, and am hooking it all together. I have 2 breakers one of them buzzes pretty loud when I turn it on. So I thought the breaker may be bad, even though it is brand new. So I switched the breakers thinking I would get the same breaker buzzing. But nope. So I think my problem is somewhere beyond the breaker boxes, in the walls. Just not sure where to start.

I am getting power to the not buzzing breaker/wire. That wire goes to just one outlet in the home. The other breaker/wire goes to 2 outlets and 2 led lights (this is the problem one) There was no load attached when I flipped the breaker.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What make and model are the breakers and panel in question?

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the panel?

Comment: What is connected to the breaker? My dimmers make my breakers buzz sometimes

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.